# How to use conditional formatting for values that are a certain amount higher than the above cell?

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, formatting, conditional-formatting

I'm having trouble using Conditional Formatting in Excel. I am inexperienced so apologies if this is an easy fix.

Basically, I have a table of accounts, and the number of orders they have in a matrix style. For each order they make, the number of days since they made that order is added into the table.

Order Quantity is the order number, so the 9th order Clara made was 2416 days ago

[image]

I wanted to show that if, for example, Abbie's 3rd order was over a year after her 2nd order (which it is), then highlight it red. If it's between 6 months and a year, yellow, and if it's under 6 months to make it green (if it's possible to have more choice that would be even better, so last 30 days, 90 days, etc.).

However, when I write this into the formula section of the conditional formatting area, and drag the formatting down, the cell numbers stay the same, so they would all base their values on whether the 5th, 6th, 7th orders were over a year since her 2nd order.

I wanted to make it to show the 3rd against 2nd, 4th against 3rd, 5th against 4th and so on. (And obviously I would like to do this with all accounts). How would I go about this?

---

The only way I can even think of it working after the problems I've had is to do them all individually, which would be very time consuming.

=$J$5 < $J$4 - 365 is the formula that is written. I've gotten rid of the $ but they automatically reappear, and even when they don't, the cells don't change.

Comment: So first make sure you progress in a logical sequence first test <6, then <12 which means any left are over a year. If you drag down a range with something like "=J4+4" then J4 will chnage to J5 etc unless you put J$4 when the row cannot change. Can't do miuch more as you don't give any detail of the formulae you used.

Comment: Your approach is right but your formula use **absolute** references and what you need is **relative** references. Check [Switch between relative, absolute, and mixed references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9) to understand why your formula does not work and then use relative references. Something like `=J5 < (J4 - 365) ` should work

Comment: Were you looking for a colorful painting like this https://imgur.com/a/2fNVaMr ? As the ones before me mentioned, you can't use absolute references when you want the rule to continue on the next, otherwise you'll color every cell red if the first 2 in the range cause it to be red. ("ISGETAL" = "ISNUMBER", "EN" = "AND" sorry for the Dutch)

Comment: Thank you everyone, I followed @Notus_Panda 's image, took me a while to realise that here in the UK, we use a comma delimiter, not a semi-colon delimiter, so was confused as to why the formula didn't work for a while :D

I don't know how to resolve this question or upvote (there are no checks, arrows, anything) so I'm writing it here :) I was able to get 10 formulae in the end, so now it looks very pretty :)

Comment: Argh, forgot to translate the ";" to ",". My bad, I should've just translated it fully here `=AND(ISNUMBER(B1),B2<B1-180)`. Glad you figured it out on your own, however, it's (imo) the best learning method, to learn while you do.

Comment: Please @Notus_Panda post your answer so the question can be closed and it can be helpful to future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time I'll translate for the non-fake-German speakers..

[image: Colorful pallet]

The formula should not be with absolute references when the conditions aren't absolute, i.e. `$B$2<$B$1-365` over the range `=$B$2:$G$13` would color all cells in that range red since B2 is in fact smaller than B1 - 365

The formulae in English:

- `AND(ISNUMBER(B1),B2>B1-180)`
- `AND(B2<B1-180,B2<B1-365)` (yes, I had
  360 in the img, don't ask why)
- `B2<B1-365` (no change there ofc)